# Can $a=\left(\sqrt{2(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{z})}-\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z}\right)^2$ be an integer if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not squares?

Tags: diophantine-equations, elementary-functions

Let $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$.Can we find 3 non-perfect squares $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z},$  such that $a \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 2$
$$a=\left(\sqrt{2(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{z})}-\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z}\right)^2$$
I cannot seem to find any such triplets. Any hints on how to prove it?

Comment: Just curious $-$ where does this expression come from?

Comment: Try for example $(3,17,20)\to a = 3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Indeed. Forgot to think. My check for the gcd was wrongly implemented. Thanks for seing the mistake.

Comment: @Winther, my take on the gcd condition is that it's irrelevant, since any gcd factors out in the expression for $a$ (i.e., you might as well assume it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking a solution given by Winther in comments beneath the OP led me to the following:

> In general, if $z=x+y$, then $a=x$.

This is seen by writing

$$\sqrt{2(\sqrt x+\sqrt z)(\sqrt y+\sqrt z)}=\sqrt x+\sqrt y+\sqrt z$$

squaring both sides and expanding to get

$$2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}+\sqrt{yz}+z)=x+y+z+2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}+\sqrt{yz})$$

and then cancelling left and right, leaving $z=x+y$.

Whether this gives *all* solutions to the OP's equation remains to be seen.  (I'm not offering an opinion one way or the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=k^2$, $z=r^2$ and $x=c^2$(with $k,r,c$ integers) then the expression becomes: $$(\sqrt {2\cdot (k+r)(c+r)}-k-r)^2$$
Now for $a$ to be an integer $$2(k+r)(c+r)=n^2$$
with $n$ integer.
We put $$k+r=2^{2p+1}\cdot t^s$$
And $$c+r=t^v$$
(or vice versa,with $v$ and $s$ both odd or even).
If $r=1$ $$k=2^{2p+1}\cdot t^s-1$$
And $$c=t^v-1$$. This can be a solution.

Comment: I just edited the title to include the stipulation that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not squares (which was present in the text but not the title).